# Water flushes, but nothing else

Tags: toilet

What could be the problem.  When flushing my toilet, the water flushes normally, it does not fill up and then drains slowly or anything funny.  It flushes normally, but toilet paper and whatever else is in there, would not flush!  This is sooooo frustrating!

Please help.

Thanks,
Haidee

Comment: sounds like it is time for a test of the old plunger. If you don't have one you should. Almost any hardware store and some grocery stores have them. Give it a good plunging and the plug may go down.

Comment: Open the cistern/tank lid and make sure the water level is filling to the minimum fill mark, and that the flush valve is opening wide enough to let out a lot of water quickly. You can test this by opening the flush valve by hand and holding it open, to see if you get a good flush. If all that is OK, you probably have a partial obstruction.